# Redux connect passes an unnecessary prop "dispatch" to a connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm connecting store to the Image component using redux connect. I only expect to retrieve there (in the Image component) one prop from Redux: "images". But I also get an additional prop: "dispatch".

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Image from "./Image";
import { imagesSelector } from "units/images/selectors";

const mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam = (state) => ({
  images: imagesSelector(state),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Image);
```

In the Image component I get:
`{ images: [...], dispatch: function(){...}}`

**The question:**
How to exclude dispatch from being passed to my component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the react-redux docs:

> If you don't specify a second argument to `connect()`, your component
>   will receive `dispatch` as a prop by default.

If you don't want this behavior, you can instead pass a second argument to the `connect` function, which would be the `mapDispatchToProps` argument.

It can be either a function or an object.

> We recommend always using the “object shorthand” form of
>   mapDispatchToProps, unless you have a specific reason to customize the
>   dispatching behavior.
>
> Note that:
>
> - Each field of the mapDispatchToProps object is assumed to be an action creator
> - Your component will no longer receive dispatch as a prop

Docs: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Image);
```

add null as a second parameter and you're good to go

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, doesn't work. Result is the same. But empty object instead of null works fine